# How to remove InstallAnywhere installed application?

Tags: macos, installanywhere

I have an application installed on a Mac, and after I removed the .app directory from my /Applications directory, I can no longer install the application due to it thinking the application is on my system and needs repair.  Where could I find a list of file / locations where InstallAnywhere to clean this off my system so I can do a fresh install?

Answer (score 0):

You must find out all the folders related to InstalledAnywhere by using following command

```
find / -name *InstallAnywhere*
```

And manually remove all the folders with

```
rm -rf *folderName*
```

`rm -rf` is the stongest command on mac to delete anyfolder along with its resouces and matadata from the system